# Convert these statements into propositional logic statements

Tags: logic

Can someone please help with this question. 
i have confusing with the question and im not sure where to start.
im new to propositional logic and have no idea about convert to a statements.

thanks guys.

Convert these statements into propositional logic statements.

The student is in the esports club or in the aquatic club. If they are in the esports club then they do not get free access to the pool. The student does get free access to the pool. Therefore the student is in the aquatic club.

Answer (score 0):

Lets separate these into individual statements

The student is in the esports club or in the aquatic club.

we can label s for student. Then we can see they might be in either club so we can us ∧ as stating they could be in either one

s∨(e∧a)

If they are in the esports club then they do not get free access to the pool.

To see if they are in a certain group we can use the → symbol to say if this statement is true. We don't know for sure if it is true so then we can us ↔ symbol to say it might be true on a certain condition

s↔(¬a∧e)

The student does get free access to the pool.

Since we can now see we have a conclusive answer to which club the student is in. We can use the ↨ symbol which means they are associated with each other.

s↨p

Therefore the student is in the aquatic club.

Now we know they are apart of the aquatic club we can use ∧a symbol to say it's true

s∧a